# Deploying Cloud Run Service fails because of VPC Connector annotation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

Deploying a new cloud run image failed today with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Annotation 'run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-connector' is not supported on resources of kind 'Service'. Supported kinds are: Revision, Job
```

This is strange since there has been no change to the annotation for a while.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, gcp stopped supporting that tag in the root service metadata. As described by the documentation, the tag should be moved to the template's metadata (see the yaml part from the [cloud run doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)).

The terraform code:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "gateway" {
  ... 
  template {
    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-egress" : "all"
        "run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-connector": google_vpc_access_connector.connector.id
      }
    }
    spec {
      ...
    }
  }
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      "run.googleapis.com/launch-stage": "BETA"

      // I had the annotation here before
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think it was ever supported in `$root.metadata.annotations`. Such settings are typically under `spec.template.metadata.annotations` because they are per-Revision.

Comment: in their official documentation for setting up a cloud run service the terraform example they provide has it in the root.metadata.annotations: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip#terraform_3